# Keep all the text phrases for data frequency

Tags: r, term-document-matrix

I have a data frame with only one column "text"

```
"text"
"User Interfaces"
"Twitter"
"Text Normalization"
"Term weighting"
"Teenagers"
"Team member replacement"
```

I would like to take a dataframe with the frequency of every phrase, like this:

```
 "User Interfaces",1
 "Twitter",1
 "Text Normalization",1
 "Term weighting",1
 "Teenagers",1
 "Team member replacement",1
```

in order to make it I use this:

```
library(tm) 
df <- read.csv("C:/Users/acel/Desktop/myphr.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
corpusD <- Corpus(VectorSource(df$text))
corpusD <- tm_map(corpusD, tolower)
corpusD <- tm_map(corpusD, removeWords, stopwords('english'))
corpusD <- tm_map(corpusD, removeNumbers)
corpusD <- tm_map(corpusD, stripWhitespace)
corpusD <- tm_map(corpusD, PlainTextDocument)
corpusD <- tm_map(corpusD, stemDocument, language = "english")
corpusC <- Corpus(VectorSource(corpusD))
matrixD <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpusC)
matrixD <- removeSparseTerms(matrixD, 0.75)
MatrixDfreq <- rowSums(as.matrix(matrixD))
MatrixDfreq<-sort(MatrixDfreq, decreasing = TRUE)
MatrixDtop30<- MatrixDfreq [1:30]
```

but when I check the result from `MatrixDtop30` I see one word counted like `user,1` and `interface,1` instead of seeing `"user interface",1`

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: You mean ***"Generate DTM of phrases rather than words"***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would be a lot easier using data.table operations.

```
library(data.table)
df = data.frame(text = c("test", "test" ,"test" , "test2", "test3", "test2"))

> df
   text
1  test
2  test
3  test
4 test2
5 test3
6 test2

setDT(df)
df = df[ , .(Number = .N), by = .(text)]

> df
    text Number
1:  test      3
2: test2      2
3: test3      1
```

**Edit**

We can include stemming with this

```
library(data.table)
library(SnowballC)
df = data.frame(text = c("test", "testing" ,"test" , "test2", "test3", "test2"))

> df
     text
1    test
2 testing
3    test
4   test2
5   test3
6   test2

df$text = wordStem(df$text, language = "porter")

> df
   text
1  test
2  test
3  test
4 test2
5 test3
6 test2

setDT(df)
df = df[ , .(Number = .N), by = .(text)]

> df
    text Number
1:  test      3
2: test2      2
3: test3      1
```

Comment: Thank you. Very nice work around but I would like to have the stemming and when I try to convert the corpusD to dataframe using this: `data.frame(text = sapply(corpusD, as.character), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` I receive this error `Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 6, 7` that's why I tried the frequencies from tm

Comment: @Keri i dont have any experience using that package. An alternative would be to run `library(SnowballC); wordStem(df$text, language = "porter")`

Comment: save it to the df obviously, but that will stem each word in the data.frame

Comment: Avoid struggling with tm package's limitations and syntax quirks, use ***quanteda*** instead. See [my advice on using quanteda for DTMs](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42953161/202229)

Answer (score 1):

In the example output you have it doesn't look like you're performing any transformations on the text such as lowercasing or removing stopwords and are just keeping the phrases as is? If so you can easily count the number of unique phrases using the `tidyverse`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

df <- data_frame(text = c("User Interfaces", "Twitter", "Text Normalization", "Term weighting", "Teenagers", "Team member replacement")
count(df, text)
                     text     n
                    <chr> <int>
1 Team member replacement     1
2               Teenagers     1
3          Term weighting     1
4                    text     1
5      Text Normalization     1
6                 Twitter     1
7         User Interfaces     1
```

or

```
text_df <- read_csv("C:/Users/acel/Desktop/myphr.csv")
count(text_df, text, sort = TRUE)
```

If you need perform transformations on the text look at the `stringr` and `tidytext` packages.